# How to change line color in Eclipse dark mode

Tags: eclipse

I switched to Dark Theme.
It looks good, except the Problems and Tasks bar below. The lines there are too flashy white.

Is there a way to adjust the color of those lines?
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/l3Orl.png)
I'm stuck with Eclipse Version: 2019-03 (4.11.0)

Comment: I don't think that's possible out of the box. However you could give the [Darkest Dark theme](https://www.eclipse.org/community/eclipse_newsletter/2017/february/article5.php) or [Eclipse Moonrise UI](https://marketplace.eclipse.org/content/eclipse-moonrise-ui-theme) a try. There are also [some ways](https://github.com/albertoruibal/eclipse_dark_css) to customize the UI through CSS but I don't really know what it's worth.

Comment: @EmmanuelChebbi The Darkest Dark theme is not open source and slows down the IDE. If you want to support Eclipse, make sure such UI glitches has been reported to Eclipse.

Comment: I tried the Darkest Dark theme, but it also gives too bright orange colors when you click on something. And I think Emmanuel had right it was reacting different. I deinstall it again